# Полный бэкап сайта на php. Оптимизировать скрипт

Tags: php, резервное-копирование

Использую скрипт для бэкапа(приведу ниже). Возникла проблема при переносе на другой хостинг(скорее всего нехватка памяти). Выдает ошибку на произвольном файле, при записи в архив. Скрипт рекурсивный. Помимо создания архива он выдает его на скачивание и удаляет с сервера старые версии, если их больше 3.

Пожалуйста, помогите оптимизировать данный скрипт(Бэкапы с помощью серверных средств не советовать, т.к. имеется необходимость именно в подобном подходе).
[Ссылка на файл скрипта](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By3g5Zun5hd_QVZIdi1OMjVPZFE/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Как основу использовал рекурсивный  скрипт by Marvin Menzerath(2012-2014).

Comment: Вы бы скрипт выложили туда, где его можно полностью в браузере посмотреть. Мало кто захочет что-то качать.  

Что логи говорят?

Comment: Все, что относится к вопросу, должно быть в **самом вопросе**. Ссылки могут служить только дополнением.

Answer (score 1):

решений несколько:
1. скорее всего отваливаеться по таймауту. увеличте таймаут. 
2. поставить git ипо крону делать автокомит и пуш на орижин
3. или забить судя по всему у вас дешманский хостин, или вообщ бесплатный, и что то оптимизироватьт под него нереально

добавьте вывод в скрипт

```
    function zipData($source, $destination) {
    if (extension_loaded('zip')) {
        if (file_exists($source)) {
            $zip = new ZipArchive();
            echo 'create zip archive'.PHP_EOL;
            if ($zip->open($destination, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)) {
                $source = realpath($source);
                echo realpath($source).PHP_EOL;
                if (is_dir($source)) {
                    $iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source);
                    // skip dot files while iterating
                    $iterator->setFlags(RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
                    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
                    foreach ($files as $file) {
//                        echo $file . '<BR>' ;
                        echo $file.PHP_EOL;
                        if (strpos($file, 'backup') === false) {
                            $file = realpath($file);
                            if (is_dir($file)) {
                                $zip->addEmptyDir(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file . '/'));
                            } else if (is_file($file)) {
                                $zip->addFromString(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file), file_get_contents($file));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else if (is_file($source)) {
                    $zip->addFromString(basename($source), file_get_contents($source));
                }
            }
            return $zip->close();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

и запускаем с помощью `php -f backup.php` где `backup.php` ваш скрипт. после смотрим где и почему отвалилось. Так же необходимо добавить `display_error(E_ALL)` в начале скрипта, для вывода ошибок в процессе выполненния.

Comment: Хостинг : https://www.digitalocean.com/ (max тариф)
  Мне важно, чтобы именно данный скрипт работал! Проблема не в таймауте или объеме памяти. Скрипт вырубается примерно через 3 -10 секунд(по разному). Такие проблемы возникли именно при переносе на хостинг. Если есть какие -либо предложения по оптимизации, то, пожалуйста, кодом.

Answer (score 0):

Если проблема все же с памятью для скрипта, можно попробовать там же в memory_limit увеличить значение.
К тому же можно разбить объем работы скрипта на несколько частей и выполнять по отдельности.